# Vim omnicomplete open documentation on demand

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I used Jedi-vim for vim python auto-completion and it works well. It has  shortcut to show preview/documentation of a function on demand.

I'm working on C++ projects now and I'm trying to use original omnicomplete+ctag to accomplish the same thing. But I can't find functions similar to  in Jedi-vim.

I don't want to show preview window all the time by doing ":set completeopt+=preview", and I don't want to use huge autocompletion plug-in like "YouCompleteMe", I just simply want to open/jump to preview on demand. Is there any way to accomplish it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find `:help preview-window` interesting.

```
" shows the definition of foo in the preview window
:ptag foo

" shows the definition of the symbol under the cursor in the preview window
<C-w>}
```

You'll need to index your project with ctags or some compatible program for that feature to work, though.

```
" doesn't need ctags
:psearch foo
```